# Find sum of roots of following equation

Tags: calculus, roots

> Find sum of roots of following equation:
> $$\frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{160}{9}.$$

I know we can find sum of roots of $ax^2 +bx+c=0$ and sum of roots is $\frac{-b}{a}$ but I need a fast way for above equation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160898/how-to-memorize-the-sum-and-product-of-roots-for-an-nth-degree-equation

Comment: The same holds for any degree polynomial since x is clearly not 0 or 1 we can multiply on both sides sum is $\frac{-b}{a}$ where b is coeff of {x^3} and a is of {x^4}

Comment: The sum of roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is of no help here, but (see the two previous comments) there is a similar formula for any polynomial equation (yours is of degree $4$).

Comment: Hint for really fast way: If $x$ is a root, then $1-x$ is also a root, and their sum is 1. How many pairs of roots are there?